# Get number from sentences python

Tags: python, regex, string, nltk

How I can get data from sentences ?

for the example
I have this sentences

```
4 bedroom 2 bath, 1469 sq
```

then I have done search word 'bath' in the sentence, but from that sentence I want get number '2' because it was my data.

How I can put number '2' from that sentence ?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a simple regex with capturing group:

```
import re
s= "3 roof 4 bath"
search_word = "bath"
res = re.search(r'(\d+)\s*{0}'.format(re.escape(search_word)), s)
if res:
    print(res.group(1))
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Lr3xge)

**Details**:

- `(\d+)` - Group 1: one or more digits are captured into Group 1 (note: if the number can contain commas or periods, use `[\d,.]+` instead of `\d+`, or a more precise `\d+(?:[,.]\d+)*`)
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `{0}' - a placeholder for the search word whose chars are escaped with`re.escape()` in order to match even if there are special regex chars in it

To access the digits, use `.group(1)` on the match data object.

Answer (score 0):

If you always have structure like this:

```
N word N word, N word
```

You can split by empty space " " and get the 2 element.

```
print str.split(sentence)[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex with lookahead assertion:

```
re.search(r"[\d]+(?=\s+bath)", "3 roof 4 bath")
```

Answer (score 0):

Clear answer for me is:

```
a = '4 bedroom 2 bath, 1469 sq'
regex = r'\b (\d*) (bath)\b'
b = re.search(regex, a).groups()
b[0]
2
```